# Как организовать добавление/вывод статей

Tags: html, дизайн

Делаю сайт на котором будут собраны ссылки на статьи по разным языкам программирования и появилось пару вопросов.

**1. Как лучше всего организовать добавление ссылок на статьи другими пользователями?**

Думал про github, но, наверное, слишком сложно будет так добавлять (для пользователей). Легче через форму или расширение для браузера.

**2. Нужно ли разделять русскоязычные и англоязычные статьи?**

Или всё-таки сделать кнопку-переключатель?

**3. Какой домен лучше всего подойдет для такого сайта?**

---

## Пару скриншотов

**Главная страница**

[image: index]

**Просмотр статей**

[image: urls]

---

P.S. заполнил таблицу статей ссылками на Хабр для визуализации.

Comment: 1. Пользователь предлагает, модератор одобряет.  
2. Да.  
3. Зимбабвийский, а то разместите ссылку на статью, а там оказывается копирайт есть, и далее все в руках справедливого законодательства.

Comment: @reinraus, про модерирование - именно так изначально и задумывалось.

Answer (score 1):

1. обычная форма
2. чекбокс "Показывать: []EN []RU"
3. какое-нибудь devtexts.com. Фантазия ваша

Comment: Всё же сделаю ссылками "все | RU | EN". Не хочу JS применять.

Comment: А чем js не угодил?

Comment: да и фантазии хватило на libprog.ru;linksdev.org;libdev.org

Comment: @danpetruk, ни чем, просто не хочу усложнять. Ссылки должны быть такими http://hostname/language/erlang - все / http://hostname/language/erlang/ru - русские и http://hostname/language/erlang/en - английские. Если же делать с чекбоксами, то POST или AJAX.